# Using python function in matlab

Tags: python, matlab

I'm trying to call the following opencv function on matlab

https://pypi.org/project/opencv-rolling-ball/

so I did the following:

```
img, background = py.cv2_rolling_ball.subtract_background_rolling_ball(img, 30,pyargs('light_background','True'), pyargs('use_paraboloid', 'False'),pyargs('do_presmooth','True');
```

The error message says

```
Invalid expression. When calling a function or indexing a variable, use parentheses. Otherwise, check
```

for mismatched delimiters.

so apparently there's some syntactic errors in my code and Matlab wouldn't recognize the function call. Could someone point me in the right direction on what I should change to make it work?

Comment: Welcoem to Stack Overflow. What makes you think you've got a _syntactic_ error? Specifically, what does "matlab wouldn't recognize the function call" mean? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What have you tried?  Add your code and any errors/output to your question and that will help others find solutions to your problem.  It may be helpful to you to read the [SO guide to asking a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks. I posted the error message I received.

Comment: It looks to me like mismatched parentheses.

Comment: Add a closing parenthesis before the semicolon on the `img, background = py.cv2_rolling_ball...` line. Voting to close as typo.